# adl not found after installing adobe air on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, air, adobe, ubuntu-18.04

I am using ubuntu 18 and following [this](https://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/adobeair-is-now-available-for-ubuntu.html) tutorial to install adobe air

Installation goes smooth, no errors (after some modification like using --fix-broken and adding i386 architecture to my machine)

I am then trying to use it like explained [here](https://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/adobe_air_hello_world_on_ubuntu_and_windows/)

But when I try to use adl I keep getting

> Command "adl" not found

What am i missing? Where is the adl command?

Answer (score 1):

The adl command is in the 'bin' folder of the directory where Air is installed.
If you don't know where the Air directory is, try this brute force (may take time):

```
find / -name adl
```

Comment: Get nothing, does it make any sense?

Comment: Did you download the SDK (as explained in the second link you referred) ? adl is only included in the SDK. It is not part of the runtime (your first link).

Comment: I installed it using the .deb file, is that not sufficient?

Comment: The .deb file is AIR runtime; it allows you to run AIR applications. But if you wish to go further and develop applications, you need to also install the SDK (Software Development Kit). adl is contained in the SDK.